# Trace listener, how to output to different files based on event type c#

Tags: c#, tracelistener

I would like to create two listeners, one for Data and one for errors. Each one outputs to different file. I would like to to decide which listener listens in my program

so what i would like:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AppListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Output/logs.log"/>
      <add name="ErrorListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="errors.log"/>
    </listeners>
  </trace>
```

In the program i would then like to make a call as such:

Trace.Writeline("AppListener", "Info: this is information");

Is this possible or something similar ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The entries in the `<listeners>` list are all invoked and you don't have control over that from the tracing side.  You *can* create an instance of `System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener` yourself in code, and use that directly instead.  Depending on what you are trying to achieve exactly, you might find it useful to [apply specific filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-use-tracesource-and-filters-with-trace-listeners) to the listeners in the `<listeners>` collection, which would allow them to act on different traces.